# Sum values for a specific date within multiple dictionaries each containing multiple dataframes in python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary

I have two dictionaries, each containing two dataframes of varying sizes, but all of which share two columns in common: 'Date' and '# of Apples'

I'm looking to create a dataframe 'results_df' that contains two columns 'Date' and 'Sum of Apples', which checks each of the four dataframes within the two dictionaries for a matching date and sums the '# of apples' for that day, placing it in the 'Sum of Apples' column of results_df.

Example of data:

```
dict1 = {'df1':Dataframe, 'df2':Dataframe}
df1 = ['Date', '# of Apples']
      2023-01-01 ... 5
      2023-01-03 ... 2
df2 = ['Date', '# of Apples']
      2023-01-01 ... 1
      2023-01-04 ... 4

dict2 = {'df3':Dataframe, 'df4':Dataframe}
df3 = ['Date', '# of Apples']
      2023-01-03 ... 2
      2023-01-04 ... 5
df4 = ['Date', '# of Apples']
      2023-01-01 ... 4
      2023-01-03 ... 3
```

Trying to achieve:

```
results_df = ['Date', 'Sum of Apples']
      2023-01-01 ... 10
      2023-01-02 ... 0
      2023-01-03 ... 7
      2023-01-04 ... 9
      2023-01-05 ... 0
      ...
```

I'm unsure how to access the dataframes within the dicts and match dates in order to get the sum using dataframes.

I looked into df concatenation but since the dataframes are of different size, I was having a lot of problems with that.  I also tried merging each dict into a single dict and then created a loop to cycle through each dict and then each dataframe within each dict but that ended up being pretty slow, so I have a feeling that's not the correct way and that there's a better way that fully utilize the power of dataframes that I just don't understand.

Appreciate any help.

Edit: this is my first post here so if more information is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your (`I/O`), the question can be interpreted in at least two ways (*see below*) :

```
​results_df = (
                pd.concat([df_ for df_ in {**dict1, **dict2}.values()],
                          ignore_index=True)
                    .assign(Date= lambda df_: pd.to_datetime(df_["Date"]))
                    .groupby("Date").sum()
                    .set_axis(["Sum of Apples"], axis=1)                    
                    .pipe(lambda df_: df_.reindex(pd.date_range(df_.index.min(),
                                                                df_.index.max(), 
                               freq="D"), fill_value=0))
                    .reset_index(names="Date")
              )
​
```

NB : If not needed, remove the statements/lines when we call [`pandas.DataFrame.pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html).

Output :

```
print(results_df, type(results_df))

        Date  Sum of Apples
0 2023-01-01             10
1 2023-01-02              0
2 2023-01-03              7
3 2023-01-04              9 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: The OP does not know how to do basic operations, and you are providing this without any explanation, lol

Comment: I do know how to do basic operations but thanks for your helpful comment.

Comment: @M04RC4GR, never mind, let me know if you need any clarification.